How to specify installation of an application from the /packages/apps folder during the build of Android 12 AOSP
Tell me if I want the Android 12 build to have the ThemePicker application from the /packages/apps folder
In which file should I add it:
In the file build/make/target/product/handheld_product.mk
I should add ThemePicker
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    Calendar \
    Camera2 \
    DeskClock \
    Gallery2 \
    LatinIME \

Or should I add to the file:
device/rockchip/common/device.mk
I have such applications in it
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    Music \
    WallpaperPicker


If you want to get answers you should accept / vote and get feedback to answers in your questions! For example: this and this.

You should avoid modifying files in directories that ship with AOSP such as build/make, otherwise you may have merge conflicts when you need to update your Android OS version or even just applying security fixes.
You should make a new directory for your device with its own git repo, usually copied from some existing project created by your chipset vendor. For example it could be device/rockchip/mydevicex. Then and make changes there since that git repo is now wholly owned by you.
Read https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/new-device#build-a-product for more details.
